# How to use character classes in searching a string in PHP

Tags: php, regex

Using a for loop, I want to cycle through each character in a string and check to see if it is a certain letter. Let's say I want to search my string for my favorite letters -- A,C,D,O,V. Let's say I have a string, $giantButtText. Why does this result in no output on my standard output (given that $giantButtText does indeed contain those letters)?

```
if($giantButtText[$i] == "/[acdov]/") echo $giantButtText[$i];
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks @PaulCrovella!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to match `$giantButtText[$i]` to a regular expression.
The standard way to do this is `preg_match()` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

Something like this should work:

```
$a = array();
$a[0] = "dadov";
if (preg_match("/[acdov]/", $a[0])) echo "true";

-> true
```